# React Router going back two pages while preserving history

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

When someone tries to access a restricted route for ex `/account/dashboard` we need to ask him to login and then redirect him back to the `/account/dashboard` page. Our login route history looks like

- /login
- /verify-otp

Using React Router's history object how do I redirect the user back to `/account/dashboard` when he successfully logins in.

Verify OTP Action

```js
export const verifyOTP = data => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { userId, profileCompleted } = getState().user
    await svysh.post(`/customer/verify-otp/${userId}`, { otp: Number(data) })
        .then((response) => {
            let verified = response.data.error ? false : true
            let token = response.data.error ? null : response.data.data.access_token
            let tokenExpiry = response.data.error ? null : Date.parse(response.data.data.expires_at)
            let isSignedIn = token ? true : false
            let errorCode = response.data.error ? response.data.code : null

            dispatch({
                type: actionTypes.VERIFY_OTP,
                accessToken: token,
                accessTokenExpiry: tokenExpiry,
                verfied: verified,
                isSignedIn: isSignedIn,
                error: response.data.error,
                errorCode: errorCode,
                message: response.data.message
            })

            dispatch(setLoading(false))

            if (verified && !profileCompleted) {
                history.push('/complete-profile')
            } else if (!verified) {
                history.push('/verify')
            } else {
                window.history.go(-2)
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Catch Error', error)
            dispatch(setLoading(false))
        })
}
```

Comment: Is there an specific reason why you wouldn't do `history.push('/account/dashboard')` instead of going two pages back?

Comment: well because there might be a lot of cases where the URL might be different. He might be visiting /account/orders or he might be visiting checkout/cart

Comment: maybe storing the user's location before it got redirected to `/login`? Would that be an option? And then `history.push(initialLocation)`

Comment: @ajmnz so i keep initiallocation in the redux store and skip updating it when the user is on the login paths. I don't know this sounds more like a hack don you think?

Comment: What I meant was, once the user lands to say `account/dashboard`, there must be a check if the user is logged in, right? If not, it gets redirected to `/login`. Why not keep in Redux store the location of where the user got redirected? I don't see it as a hack, tbh. There must be some react-router-way to do this, but atm I haven't come across it

Comment: @ajmnz Well its not just restricted routes, A user might on a 3rd category level and then try to login. He should be redirect back to the same page he attempted to log in from. Thats how it should be right?

Comment: It definitely should be like that. Just so I understand better, why does `history.go(-2)` doesn't work for you?

Comment: I am redirected but back, sometimes im redirected to the homepage sometimes to the login page

Comment: @ajmnz im thinking to go your way, storing a referrer variable in the redux store and using that to redirect back. I'll disable it for the login pages. I use redux persist so I can also store that across page refreshes

Comment: Sounds good! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to solve this problem I created a seperate LinkItem component and now will use this component for all links in my app. When someone clicks on the link I set a referrer variable in the store and after someone has logged in, i see if the referrer is present I redirect to the referrer if not I redirect to the homepage.

LinkItem

```
import LinkItem from '../../../extras/LinkItem'

<LinkItem
    to='/account/orders'
    list='true'
    text='Orders'
/>
```

Link Component

```js
import { ListItem } from '@material-ui/core'

class LinkItem extends React.Component {

    handleReferrer() {
        const { to } = this.props
        this.props.setReferrer(to)
    }

    render() {
        const { list, to, text } = this.props
        return (
            <>
                {list &&
                    <ListItem
                        component='a'
                        disableGutters
                        href={to}
                        onClick={() => this.handleReferrer()}
                    >
                        {text}
                    </ListItem>
                }
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Redirect on OTP Verfied

```js
export const verifyOTP = data => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { userId, profileCompleted } = getState().user
    const { referrer } = getState().global
    await svysh.post(`/customer/verify-otp/${userId}`, { otp: Number(data) })
        .then((response) => {
            let verified = response.data.error ? false : true
            let token = response.data.error ? null : response.data.data.access_token
            let tokenExpiry = response.data.error ? null : Date.parse(response.data.data.expires_at)
            let isSignedIn = token ? true : false
            let errorCode = response.data.error ? response.data.code : null

            dispatch({
                type: actionTypes.VERIFY_OTP,
                accessToken: token,
                accessTokenExpiry: tokenExpiry,
                verfied: verified,
                isSignedIn: isSignedIn,
                error: response.data.error,
                errorCode: errorCode,
                message: response.data.message
            })

            dispatch(setLoading(false))

            if (verified && !profileCompleted) {
                history.push('/complete-profile')
            } else if (!verified) {
                history.push('/verify')
            } else {
                if (referrer) {
                    history.push(referrer)
                } else {
                    history.push('/')
                }
                
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Catch Error', error)
            dispatch(setLoading(false))
        })
}
```

**EDIT:**
This approach was sugguested by @ajmnz